# How to add a ruby library in Rhomobile Application

Tags: ruby, pdf, rhomobile

I want to use Prawn or PDFkit library for generating PDF into my Rhomobile application.
Please suggest the process.

I was using pdf_writer which is supported by Rhomobile but there are issues including images in the generated pdfs.

Plz help

Answer (score 1):

Adding image with using pdf_writer is possible but using tricky way. first you  need to store that image in DB as a blob data, then through query you need to fetch blob data from that table and need to print that blob data on PDF. 
**Note :** this is only applicable for for raw RGB formatted images.